# Deleting unused CSS from master page in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I've a couple of css file that were used in previous versions of the master page but now they are not referenced in the page. However, while i try to delete them, the following error message prompts:

`Server error: This item cannot be deleted because it is still referenced by other pages.`

I've gone through some older forum suggestions and there seems to be a hack by creating a temp folder, moving those css files into the temp folder and deleting the folder itself after turning off all the versioning thing. But, the domain that has the method written clearly has expired and I don't seem to have a specific solution to this thing as of now.

I'd be grateful to have a little help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to deactivated publishing feature and then delete the files.

Or create a new master page and apply the master page to default, then delete the master page.

And try to delete master page using PowerShell.

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint.site.com/"
$masterpageGallery = $spWeb.GetFolder("_catalogs/masterpage")
$masterpage = $masterpageGallery.Files["MyMasterPage.master"]
$masterpage.Delete();
$spWeb.Dispose();
```

Comment: Try to delete master page using powershell.